# I have been working on this code and I called my method replaceLessThan(x,e), and I can't properly write this method

Tags: java

```
public class ArrayExamples {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    int c = 3;
    int d =2;
    System.out.println("c is " + c + " d is " + d);
    swapInts(3,2);
        int [] a = {1,2,3};
        int [] b = {2,2,3};
        int [] x = {3,45,17,2,-1,44,9,23,67,2,-6,-23,-100,12,5,1212};
        int e = 12;
        System.out.println();
        for ( int z: a){
            System.out.print( z + " ");

        }
        System.out.println();
        for ( int y: b){
            System.out.print( y + " ");
        }
        swapIntArrays (a,b);
        System.out.println();
        for ( int z: x){
            System.out.print( z + " ");
        }

        replaceLessThan(x,e);
    }


    public static void replaceLessThan(int[] x, int e) {    
        System.out.println();
        for (int counter = 0 ; counter<x.length; counter++){
            if ( x[counter] < e){

                System.out.print (x[counter] + " ");
            }

        }

    }


    public static void swapInts(int c, int d){
        int temp = c;
        c=d;
        d=temp;
        System.out.println("c is " + c + " c is " + d);


    }

    public static void swapIntArrays (int []a, int []b){
        System.out.println();
        for(int i1=0; i1 < a.length; i1++){
            int temp = a[i1];
            a[i1] = b[i1];
            b[i1]= temp;

            System.out.print(a[i1] + " ");

        }
        System.out.println();

        for(int i1=0; i1 < b.length; i1++){
            System.out.print(b[i1] + " ");
        }

        System.out.println();
    }

}
```

my other methods are working fine but I can't figure out how to manipulate the int[]x array to get 12 to replace all numbers less than 12. I can get numbers less than 12 from int[]x to print but I can't get 12 to replace all the numbers less than 12

Comment: You want to replace numbers less than `e` with what ? or you want to remove it from array ?

Comment: i want to replace all numbers less than e with 12 so that the output is the original array with 12 replacing numbers smaller than it.

Comment: so orginal array is int [] x = {3,45,17,2,-1,44,9,23,67,2,-6,-23,-100,12,5,1212}; i want output of { 12,45,17,12,12,44,12,23,67,12,12,12,12,12,12,1212}

Comment: see the posted answer for solution.

Answer (score 1):

Modify your `replaceLessThan` method as given below to replace all the elements less than `e`.

```
    public static void replaceLessThan(int[] x, int e) {    
        System.out.println();
        for (int counter = 0 ; counter<x.length; counter++){
            if ( x[counter] < e){
                x[counter] = e; // Add this line to replace elements.
            }
            System.out.print (x[counter] + " "); // Move this statement out of if condition             
        }
```

Comment: yeah but i still want the output of the other numbers. so orginal array is  [] x = {3,45,17,2,-1,44,9,23,67,2,-6,-23,-100,12,5,1212}; and i want an output of 12,45,17,12,12,44,12,23,67,12,12,12,12,12,12,1212}

Comment: so essentially the method should accept an integer and another 
integer, Iterate over the array and replace all numbers less than the number with the value of 
the second parameter

Comment: Above method will print whole array, please run and test it.

Comment: interesting so how does moving it out of if statement make it run correctly like it does?

Comment: In if it will print the values which are `< e`, outside if it will print all.